# Indexing a Text File in Python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a text file with a list of 4 digit codes inside of it as such:

```
4317
2352
2315
```

At a point in my code I ask users to input there 4 digit code, what I want to do is to then match it so if they say their code is 4317 it gives me 0 and then I want to use that number to find something in a second list that is full of names as such:

```
John
Jen
James
Joe
```

So if I type in 4317 it gives me 0 and then I want to print what number 0 thing is in the second list. I am completely stumped on how to do this, both lists are in separate .txt files.

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to include the python code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
with open('first.txt') as  f, open('second.txt') as f2:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines_2 = f2.readlines()
    lns = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    lns_2 = [line.strip() for line in lines_2]


lns = list(map(int, lns))
lns_2 = list(map(int, lns_2))

n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
if n in lns:
    print(lns.index(n))
    print(lns_2[lns.index(n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Open both files, loop over each line together using `zip()` (assuming each file has same number of lines)

```
usercode = input("code:")
with open("f1.txt") as codes, open("f2.txt") as names:
    for code, name in zip(codes, names):
        if code == usercode:
            print(name)
            break
```